# attempting to multiply 2 variables and I keep getting an error

Tags: python

im trying to make a circle area calculator. here is my code and the error.

```
import time
import math
print("Circle Area Calculator")
time.sleep(0.5)
radius = input("input radius")
print ("calculating")
print("...")
radius2 = (radius*radius)
ans = (3.14*radius2)
print(ans)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>>
```

Comment: What type is the `radius` variable?

Comment: @DerekO Seems to be a `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python input function takes the given input as a string, and two strings cannot be multiplied together. You need to cast the input to an integer or float before you do any math on it.

```
radius = float(input())
```

Comment: oh my god, im so dumb for not realizing that. thank you so much, I've spent 2 days trying to fix it. that finally did it. thank you so much